# Firefox File Upload Box is bigger than Chrome/IE/Safari - How to fix? - use size(HTML) and width(CSS) parameters

Tags: css, firefox, xhtml

Chrome, IE, and Safari...all have teh same interpretaions of my CSS for a file upload box...but Firefox...does not adhere to the width property..by about 40 px...so it looks..bad.

How do I handle this...How do I make Firefox conform similarly to Chrome, IE, and Safari?

It looks like I might need to use a Firefox extentsion but which one and how?

[image]

File Upload CSS

```
input.te7
  {
  background:#ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top:3px;
  width:250px;
  height:33px;
  border:1px solid #eeeeee;
  font-size:18px;
  }
input.te7:hover
  {
  border:1px solid #888888;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a input:

```
input{
width: 250;
}
```

it should be the same on all browsers, if not, try this:

```
<input type="text" name="sized" size="25" />
```

Then change the other declarations in the css.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Exactly Firefox uses html "size"...while IE, Chrome, and Safari use CSS width.

Comment: Is there a way to set size in the CSS?

Comment: Not for Firefox, as he said, you should use both to be "safe"